# Independence of $\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$ whereby $X$ and $Y$ are iid r.v. and standard-normally distributed

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, independence

> Let $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two real-valued, independent and identically distributed random variables. Now we additionally assume that $X$ and $Y$ are standard-normally distributed. Show that the random variables $\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}$ are independent under these assumptions.

I know that two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if
$$
F_{X Y}(x, y)=F_X(x) F_Y(y) \quad \forall\, x, y \in \mathbb{R},
$$
where $F_{X, Y}(x, y)$ is their joint distribution function and $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$ are their marginal distribution functions.

Besides, I also got this hint:

> The matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
> \end{matrix}\right)$ describes a rotation by $45^{\circ}$.

Any hints on how to tackle this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : Gaussian vectors are independant if and only if their covariance matrix is diagonal and linear combination of gaussian vectors is still gaussian.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the joint distribution. We do _not_ have $F_{\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}}(x,y) = F_{\frac{X^2-Y^2}{\sqrt{2}}}(x,y)$ (there's a comma). Instead, we have that $F_{\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}}(x,y)=P\left(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{2}}\leq x, \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt{2}}\leq y\right) = \iint_{a,b|\frac{a-b}{\sqrt2}\leq x,\frac{a+b}{\sqrt2}\leq y} f_{X,Y}(a,b)\ \mathrm da\mathrm db$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independant and standard-normally distributed variables, the couple $(X, Y)$ is a gaussian vector, wich covariance matrix $I_2$. Let
$$A := \begin{pmatrix}1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt2\\ 1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt2\end{pmatrix}.$$
The vector $(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt2}, \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt2}) = A \cdot (X, Y)$ is also a gaussian vector with $A I_2 A^T=AA^T$ as its covariance matrix. Since $A$ is the $\pi/2$-rotation, it is an orthognal matrix and $AA^T = I_2$. Hence, $\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt2}$ and $\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt2}$ are independent.